# Modify the output URL in WordPress to include another folder

Tags: php, wordpress, supersized

I've been struggling with this for days trying to modify every part of the string possible to include a different folder. I'm using the Supersized jQuery slider in the PhotoArtist theme. If you want to see it live here's the link: http://www.arjanbaagh.com/testsite/sliders-list/bridal-2013-collection/.

What I am trying to achieve is modify the `$output` string to include a different folder before the filename. I'm attempting to use a different thumbnail for the preview. Currently the slider pulls the image  from the main preview and scales it down dynamically. Here is the line of PHP code that shows a thumbnail on the page:

```
$output .=" thumb : ". "'" . get_template_directory_uri() . "/framework/timthumb/timthumb.php?src=".thumb_link($element['img']) .  "&w=300&h=150'}";
```

This outputs the following URL:

http://www.arjanbaagh.com/testsite/wp-content/themes/photoartist-parent/framework/timthumb/timthumb.php?src=http://www.arjanbaagh.com/testsite/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/image02.jpg&w=300&h=150

All I want to do is change the `$output` string so that it includes another folder before image02.jpg. So for example, I want to change the URL to:

http://www.arjanbaagh.com/testsite/wp-content/themes/photoartist-parent/framework/timthumb/timthumb.php?src=http://www.arjanbaagh.com/testsite/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/**newfolder**/image02.jpg&w=300&h=150

I've tried modifying the directory in the $output string but I can only change the beginning or the end of the string.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do the images always stem from the `uploads` folder?

Comment: Hi @AdamD, yep thats right. All of the images from the slider come from the uploads folder. The thumbnails are currently just a dynamically scaled down version of the large preview images so the thumbnails are not stored anywhere. I just want to redirect the URL to a new folder where I can create custom thhumbnails. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this below your existing `$output` string:

```
/* Set the $output URL to a variable */    
$url = explode('/', $output);

/* Grab the last segment of the URL (image name and parameters) */
$lastSegment = end($url); // image02.jpg&w=300&h=150

/* Grab the first part of the entire original $output URL before the image string */
$partialUrl = explode($lastSegment, $output); // gets first part of url before image02.jpg&w=300&h=150

/* Grab the first returned value from $partialUrl, which is the string before the image name */
$firstHalf = $partialUrl[0]; // http://www.arjanbaagh.com/testsite/wp-content/themes/photoartist-parent/framework/timthumb/timthumb.php?src=http://www.arjanbaagh.com/testsite/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/

/* Add your directory */
$stringToAdd = 'newfolder/';

/* Final $output with your new directory in place */
$output = $firstHalf.$stringToAdd.$lastSegment
```

Comment: you are a legend!! Thank you so much for your help. Your code worked (with a tiny tweak). I placed the code under the existing $output string and voila!! I did have to change $partialUrl = explode('$lastSegment', $output); to $partialUrl = explode($lastSegment, $output); without the quotes and it worked perfectly. The way you broke it down has made it easier to understand how you did it. Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: No problem - and sorry about the typo with the variable in quotes. I have fixed the answer for anyone else :)